# Is there a way to check if a folder exists in a Firebase cloud function (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to check if a folder exists in a Firebase cloud function (JavaScript)?
I've tried using `bucket.file().exists()`, but that only works for files.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Storage operates with a flat namespace, which means that folders don't actually exist within Cloud Storage. The concept of folders is emulated by using `prefix` and `separators` when listing object names.

[Google Cloud Storage - Folders](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders)

Comment: I actually had to create an empty file on the root of each "folder" to simulate folders.